# How do you separate the duplicated from the non-duplicated numbers into two lists by using an if/else statement?

Tags: python

I was able to find a way to compare all of the numbers in the three lists. Should a number be present in all three lists, I would have to add it to the matching_numbers list. If a number doesn’t match any of the other numbers, then I would have to add it to the unique_numbers list. Duplicates found in two of three lists are considered unique numbers, therefore they should go into the unique_numbers list.

```
list_1 = []

list_2 = []

list_3 = []

matching_numbers = []

unique_numbers = []

countone = 0

counttwo = 0

countthree = 0

exit = 0

import random

name = input("Hello USER. What will your name be?")

print("Hello " + name + ". Welcome to the NUMBERS program.")

amountone = int(input("How many numbers do you wish to have for your first list? Please choose from between 1 and 15."))

while countone != amountone:
  x = random.randint(1, 30)
  list_1 += [x,]
  print(list_1)
  countone += 1

amounttwo = int(input("For your second list, how many numbers do you wish to have? Please choose from between 1 and 15."))

while counttwo != amounttwo:
  x = random.randint(1, 30)
  list_2 += [x,]
  print(list_2)
  counttwo += 1

amountthree = int(input("For your third list, how many numbers do you wish to have? Please choose from between 1 and 15."))

while countthree != amountthree:
  x = random.randint(1, 30)
  list_3 += [x,]
  print(list_3)
  countthree += 1

for a in list_1:
  for b in list_2:
    for c in list_3:
      if a == b and b == c:
        matching_numbers = list(set(list_1) & set(list_2) & set(list_3))
      else:
        unique_numbers =
```

Comment: Can there be duplicate numbers within one of the lists?  If not, you might use sets instead, and take advantage of the built in set intersections, unions, and differences.

Comment: If you're asking whether there can be duplicates within one list, then yes. This is actually an assignment that was meant to use different list methods and although I was able to figure out most of the system, the only exception was the unique_numbers part, which is what I'm confused on.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Using just list methods, (you could also use sets or `collections.Counter`) you can do something like:

```
def separate(*lists):
    unique_values = []
    duplicate_values = []
    for list_ in lists:
        for value in list_:
            if all(value in l for l in lists):
                if value not in duplicate_values:
                    duplicate_values.append(value)
            else:
                if value not in unique_values:
                    unique_values.append(value)
     return unique_values, duplicate_values
```

I encourage you to try to rewrite this using sets, to appreciate how they would make this code faster and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

try using sets:

```
import random

list_1 = [random.randint(0, 30) for _ in range(30)]
list_2 = [random.randint(0, 30) for _ in range(30)]
list_3 = [random.randint(0, 30) for _ in range(30)]

matched_numbers = set.union(set(list_1).intersection(set(list_2)), set(list_1).intersection(set(list_3)), set(list_2).intersection(set(list_3)))
unique_numbers = set.difference(set.union(set(list_1), set(list_2), set(list_3)), matched)
```

Note: only reason for juggling between sets and lists here is to permit duplicates in the original input. If that's not needed, replace `list_1`, `list_2`, and `list_3` with sets instead.